# SharePoint 2013 Popularity trends mystery

Tags: sharepoint-server

In our sharepoint 2013 root site we have a pages library which also contains the home page for the site collection as well.Popularity trends reports are getting updated daily for the home page but other pages in the same pages library are not showing any page views. Timer jobs, event receivers etc are all working. I have looked in the logging db and I can see the pages showing 0 views in the reprots have been accessed number of times by different users. Home page is getting around 140 views every day and other pages in the same page library are getting around 15 views every day. Other subsites in the same site collection are showing page views even if numbers are around 2-3 views per day.   What could be the reason for this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this mystry now. Issue was that the seach index was not getting updated due to low disk space on my app server.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if you have the correct settings in Central Administration / Usage Data Collection. Please double check if ' Page Requests' are selected?
Thanks
Ova

Comment: Thanks Ova. Page Requests are selected. Thats why whole thing seems a bit mysterious to me.